# Finding $f(100)$ given that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $98$ and $f (k)=\frac 1 k$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots,98,99$

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations

A polynomial of degree $98$ such $f (k)=\frac 1 k$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots,98,99$  exists.
How can I find $f(100)$?
What are the possible methods?

Comment: a polynomial of degree 98 has 99 coefficients. are you sure there are only 98 conditions on f? Because then you can have any value for f(100) ...

Comment: He probably meant "for $k=1,2,\dots,99$ exists."

Comment: Sorry typo updated :) @coproc

Comment: What is the value of $kf(k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\dots,99$?

Comment: That is surely 1 @columbus8myhw

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Except for $k=0$, in which case $kf(k)$ is $0$. This function should be easier to deal with!

Comment: it's like f (1)=2f (2)=3f (3) and so on..OK im  thinking

Comment: +1 This is one of the more unique questions I've seen today...where or how did you come across this?

Comment: ^This sort of question comes up frequently in high school level math competitions.

Comment: I think I remember almost the exact same question from an old ARML team round, but I could be wrong.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/problems/find-p100-_/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on Akiva Weinberger columbus's hint.

Consider the polynomial $$kf(k)-1$$

which has degree 99 is zero for all $k=1,2,3, \cdots, 99$.

So you know the polynomial $kf(k)-1$ has the form $$C(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdots(k-99)$$

and you can find $C$ when you put $k=0$.

In general, its a good idea to find a polynomial that has as many zeros as its degree is.

Comment: great solution, and $C = \frac{-1}{99! \cdot (-1)^{99}} = \frac{1}{99!}$